# About definition of "depth"

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, definition

In Gorenstein's Finite Group Theory book on page 189,

> "It will be convenient to introduce the terms depth, normal depth, and characteristic depth of a $p$-group $P$ to denote the maximum of $m(A)$, where $A$ ranges respectively over all abelian, all normal abelian, and all
>   characteristic abelian subgroups of $P$."

I could not really understand the definition of depth, normal depth, and characteristic depth from above part. If someone could explain these terms, I would be thankful.

Comment: What is $m$? $ $

Comment: What don't you understand exactly?

Comment: Firstly I could not find definition of $m(A)$ is this book. I also search on pdf file, and it seems that it is the first place it is used.

Comment: There is a list of notation onpage 519. You will see there that $m(G)$ is defined on page 8.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you very much. So $m(A)$ is the rank of $A$ as far as I understand (The minimum required elements to generate $A$)?